# Take screenshot of URL certificate Chrome - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to take screenshot of certificate information(General tab) of an URL. I'm using selenium with Java. Within page I'm able to access elements but certificate icon is adjacent to address bar.

[image: sample]

Comment: You need Selenium to take a screenshot of this window? Why? 

Can you clarify exactly what is problematic regarding "certificate icon is adjacent to address bar."

Finally, I think I have an idea to solve this, but it will depend -- which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm automating taking screenshot of an URL certificate. Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Selenium has a built in screenshot function, but I expect it might not work to capture this Certificate if it is not part of the browser itself. In any case, that would be done like this:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

If that doesn't work, another idea I had is to use selenium to press keys and get a screenshot through the OS. Let's say, instead of printscreen, you set Windows to take a screenshot whenever you press, like, CTRL+e or whatever. That, for example, could be sent just like this

```
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "e");
driver.findElement(By.whatever("anything")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

(you have to import `Keys` and `By` for this)